# Midi keyboard to ipad not working

Tags: ipad, midi

I have a new ipad pro, a midi keyboard and a lightening to usb converter cable.
I connect them, and of course it does not work.

What do i need to make this work?

Comment: What it do you expect to work?. Midi keyboards are not useful to simulate the Siri functions or any action on the main iPad interface tbh.

Comment: In particular, what MIDI software on the iPad are you trying to use?